# C++ Regex: non-greedy match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, c++14, regex-greedy

I'm currently trying to make a regex which matches URL parameters and extracts them.

For example, if I got the following parameters string `?param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue`, `std::regex_match` should extract the following contents:

- `param1`
- `some_content`
- `param2`
- `some_other_content`

After trying different regex patterns, I finally built one corresponding to what I want: `std::regex("(?:[\\?&]([^=&]+)=([^=&]+))*")`.

If I take the previous example, `std::regex_match` matches as expected. However, it does not extract the expected values, keeping only the last captured values.

For example, the following code:

```
std::regex paramsRegex("(?:[\\?&]([^=&]+)=([^=&]+))*");
std::string arg = "?param1=someValue&param2=someOtherValue";
std::smatch sm;

std::regex_match(arg, sm, paramsRegex);
for (const auto &match : sm)
   std::cout << match << std::endl;
```

will give the following output:

```
param2
someOtherValue
```

As you can see, param1 and its value are skipped and not captured.

After searching on google, I've found that this is due to greedy capture and I have modified my regex into `"(?:[\\?&]([^=&]+)=([^=&]+))\\*?"` in order to enable non-greedy capturing.

This regex works well when I try it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Ds2LImtW2i) but it does not match when I use it in C++ (`std::regex_match` returns false and nothing is captured).

I've tried different `std::regex_constants` options (different regex grammar by using `std::regex_constants::grep`, `std::regex_constants::egrep`, ...) but the result is the same.

Does someone know how to do non-greedy regex capture in C++?

Comment: Each repeatition of a capturing group overwrite the previous. You need to remove the quantifier `[?&]([^=]+)=([^&]+)` and to use the regex iterator to get the different matches: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator . It is not a greedy/non-greedy problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations: I've tried with regex_iterators and it works well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) explained in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007942/c-regex-non-greedy-match#comment48134487_30007942), I just need to:

- remove the quantifier
- Use `std::regex_iterator`

It gives me the following code:

```
std::regex paramsRegex("[\\?&]([^=]+)=([^&]+)");
std::string url_params = "?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4";
std::smatch sm;

auto params_it = std::sregex_iterator(url_params.cbegin(), url_params.cend(), paramsRegex);
auto params_end = std::sregex_iterator();

while (params_it != params_end) {
    auto param = params_it->str();

    std::regex_match(param, sm, paramsRegex);
    for (const auto &s : sm)
       std::cout << s << std::endl;

    ++params_it;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
?key1=val1
key1
val1
&key2=val2
key2
val2
&key3=val3
key3
val3
&key4=val4
key4
val4
```

The orignal regex `(?:[\\?&]([^=&]+)=([^=&]+))*` was just changed into `[\\?&]([^=]+)=([^&]+)`.

Then, by using `std::sregex_iterator`, I get an iterator on each matching groups (`?key1=val1`, `&key2=val2`, ...).

Finally, by calling `std::regex_match` on each sub-string, I can retrieve parameters values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  match_results::prefix/suffix:

```
string match_expression("your expression");
smatch result;
regex fnd(match_expression, regex_constants::icase);
while (regex_search(in_str, result, fnd, std::regex_constants::match_any)) 
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < result.size(); i++)
    {           
        std::cout << result[i].str();
    }
    in_str = result.suffix();
}
```